# Jquery won't show errors nor will it validate

Tags: jquery, validation

I'e been trying to get my form to validate (without jquery validate). For some reason the code isn't cutting it and it's actually causing some css issues on my local environment.

I'm literally just trying to validate four fields and have the errors show.

```
        required = ["id_first_name", "id_last_name", "id_firmbox", "id_job_title"];

        errornotice = $("#error");
        emptyerror = "Please fill out this field.";
        $("#startform").submit(function(){
            //Validate required fields
            for (i=0;i<required.length;i++) {
                var input = $('#'+required[i]);
                if ((input.val() == "") || (input.val() == emptyerror)) {
                    input.addClass("tobefixed");
                    input.val(emptyerror);
                    errornotice.fadeIn(750);
                } else {
                    input.removeClass("tobefixed");
                }
            }

            //if any inputs on the page have the class 'tobefixed' the form will not submit
            if ($(":input").hasClass("tobefixed")) {
                return false;
            } else {
                errornotice.hide();
                requiredeturn true;
            }
        });
        $(":input").focus(function(){
            if ($(this).hasClass("tobefixed") ) {
                $(this).val("");
                $(this).removeClass("tobefixed");
            }
        });
```

I made a [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/8YgNT/11/). Maybe someone else can spot what I'm doing wrong. (I apologize for the formatting issues. I'm using Ubuntu and everything is going awry) .

Your help is greatly appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was a syntax error in your code.

Change:

```
       if ($(":input").hasClass("tobefixed")) {
            return false;
        } else {
            errornotice.hide();
            requiredeturn true;
        }
```

To:

```
    if ($(":input").hasClass("tobefixed")) {
        return false;
    } else {
        errornotice.hide();
        return true;
    }
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/8YgNT/12/

I would also recommend getting a good client debugger such as Firebug.  This error would have been pretty apparent in its console.

Answer (score 2):

If you see on JavaScript's console, you'll see the error is caused by this: `requiredeturn true;` in here:

```
  } else {
      errornotice.hide();
      requiredeturn true;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Very quickly, I can see the line `requiredeturn true;`

changing it in the jsFiddle makes it work.

http://jsfiddle.net/mWYMf/